# Running a Method after returning a POST request response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, controller, nestjs

I'm pretty new to JS and I'm using NestJS with mongo to develop a backend api. I have a basic CRUD operations. I want to be able to create the document, return it to the user and run another method without impacting the user.

```
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() body: Dto, @Headers('id') id: string) {   
    body.id = id;    
    const item = await this.service.create(body);
    return item;

  // Now, I want to call another method async to trace history changes 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have recommended calling an asynchronous call without awaiting it. While this will work to an extent, synchronous code in the method will still be executed before you respond to your caller. In other words, if your other async method to "trace history changes" looked something like this

```js
async function trackHistoryChanges(item) {
  const items = item.split('original');
  const originalItem = items[0];
  const newItem = items[1];
  if (originalDoc.trim() !== newDoc.trim()) {
    const diff = originalDoc.split(newDoc).join('')
    const docId = newDoc.split('\n')[0];
    await updateDatabase(docId, diff);
  }
}
```

all of the code up until your await (and possibly more) would still be executed.

To avoid this, you can use the [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/understanding-setimmediate) function. Your resulting code would look like this

```js
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() body: Dto, @Headers('id') id: string) {   
    body.id = id;    
    const item = await this.service.create(body);
    return item;

    // Now, I want to call another method async to trace history changes 
    setImmediate(() => trackHistoryChanges(item));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for making me aware of that function :)
Unfortunately the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to tackle this option

- Fire and forget - call the async operation without awaiting it and then return it to user. this way your call will be taken but node woudln't wait for response to come.
- Second approach is doing things in parallel to reduce the time it takes to process two requests. You could use `Promise.all` and do two things in parallel. THis is the recommended way. See example here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: The second task can happen only after I create the document. I was thinking about doing Promise.then() and call my method, but I don't want the user to wait for the second task.

Comment: then you either need to do it in then or fire and forget

Comment: As @AshishModi said, in the first bullet, await the service to create your resource, then call your method with history trace, don't await it ( `this.historyService.trace()` ), and then `return item`. This way, you will sent to your user the POST response and fire your history trace method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TypeORM, a clean way would be to use an entity listener or a subscriber. This allows you to run code "afterInsert": https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md

Answer (score 0):

You could add a call to another async method

```
@Post()
async create(@Body() body: Dto, @Headers('id') id: string) {   
  body.id = id;    
  const item = await this.service.create(body);
  this.service.anotherAsyncMethod(); 

  return item;
}
```