# Does NestJS guarantee to run async methods after return?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nestjs

What will happen when a code without `await` an async function returns from a REST API of NestJS?

```
// modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829254
@Post()
async create(@Body() body: Dto, @Headers('id') id: string) {   
  body.id = id;    
  const item = await this.service.create(body);
  this.service.anotherAsyncMethod().then(...).catch(...); 

  return item;
}
```

In this example, does the process always live to run the complete anotherAsyncMethod?
If it does, how can it be? Do NestJS or Javascript itself guarantee the way to execute?

It seems there are some waitings in simple test code.

```
async function asyncFunction() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("after 3s"), 3000);
}
asyncFunction();
console.log('END');

// output
// END
// after 3s
```

But I could not find the clue that it always work in NestJS scenario and the others.

Comment: I would think it's less to do with nestjs and more to do with your deployment. Some "serverless" cloud providers kill processes after they responded to http requests and rather start them up the next time they're needed again.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. I found that it may works strangely in serverless computation like aws lambda; https://levelup.gitconnected.com/avoiding-the-pitfalls-of-async-node-js-functions-in-aws-lambda-941220582e7a
I hope that common web servers deployed ordinarily would not kill the processes not awaited, then...

Comment: Yes. Normally node.js runs code to completion. It doesn't just randomly forget about computations still to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, any piece of code that comes before the return statement will be executed. Do not forget that the *await* statement will only wait for the result, and if you put *await* before an *async* operation, it will wait for its result, but even if you did not put *await*, the async operation still placed in the event loop and will still be executed.

The only principle is that all these operations should be before the *return* statement. The *return* means termination of that function. Not only in JavaScript but in all languages, nothing will be executed after *return*.

```js
function someOperations(status) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(status)
        res('done');
      }, 3000);
  });
}

(async () => {
  console.log('start...');
  await someOperations('first');
  someOperations('second');
  console.log('second someOperations skipped for now');
  return;
  console.log('unreachable'); // will not be executed
})()
```